# UITableView beginUpdates() and endUpdates() clarification

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm hoping someone can clarify the usage of `UITableView`'s `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`.

If I have multiple changes (`deleteRows`, `insertRows`, `moveRow` etc.) calls, should I use subsequent calls as if the previous calls have completed already?

For example:

My data was [A, B, C] (assuming only 1 section), I've updated my datasource to [B, D, C] and I wish to delete A, and then insert D between B and C, should I do the following:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), with: .automatic)
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0), with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

where I assume the delete would happened before the insert or

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), with: .automatic)
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0), with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

where the delete would not have happened yet?

I'm using Swift 4, although targeting iOS 9 so I can't use `performBatchUpdates` exclusively. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found the clarification I was looking for. From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html, under the heading "Batch Insertion, Deletion, and Reloading of Rows and Sections" and subheading "Ordering of Operations and Index Paths"

> You might have noticed something in the code shown in Listing 7-8 that seems peculiar. The code calls the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: method after it calls insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:. However, this is not the order in which UITableView completes the operations. It defers any insertions of rows or sections until after it has handled the deletions of rows or sections. The table view behaves the same way with reloading methods called inside an update block—the reload takes place with respect to the indexes of rows and sections before the animation block is executed. This behavior happens regardless of the ordering of the insertion, deletion, and reloading method calls.
>
> Deletion and reloading operations within an animation block specify which rows and sections in the original table should be removed or reloaded; insertions specify which rows and sections should be added to the resulting table. The index paths used to identify sections and rows follow this model. Inserting or removing an item in a mutable array, on the other hand, may affect the array index used for the successive insertion or removal operation; for example, if you insert an item at a certain index, the indexes of all subsequent items in the array are incremented.

While that's barely parsable, I think it means the second of example in the question is correct.

Comment: You are correct. Deleting and reloading are for the original table, use original table IndexPaths. Insertions are for the new table, use IndexPaths for the new table. AND deletes happen before insertions.